# Handling Qt C++ events in QML context

Tags: c++, qt, events, qml

The C++ API has `QEvent` along with multiple other classes derived from it (`QMouseEvent`, `QGestureEvent` etc.). QML on the other hand has events too. However I am struggling to find an elegant way of directly processing C++ events in QML.

Usually what I do is I create a custom `QQuickWidget` (or similar including `QQmlEngine`), override the `QWidget::event(QEvent* event)` and upon receiving a specific C++ event I propagate it through signals to QML slots with the QML code being loaded through that widget. This seems like a lot of work and I'm wondering if there is some sort of QML built-in event handling for events that come from C++ context.

In particular I'm interested in handling `QGestureEvent`s in QML but I guess what works for this type of events should also work for any other type of event.

Comment: Have you tried using [MultiPointTouchArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-multipointtoucharea.html) ? It has a signal `gestureStarted(GestureEvent gesture)` that could maybe answer your needs.

Comment: The thing is I want to capture gesture events that are really coming from a C++ context. For example if I'm mapping data from a device (which can be accessed only through C++ means) to the gesture API of Qt and then pass it on to the QML part of the application. It may not even be remotely connected to touch (for example making gestures using a Kinect device).

Comment: "This seems like a lot of work" - it is literally **nothing** compared to the amount of work it would take to implement C++ event handling for QML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support for event handling in QML, even keyboard and mouse are accessible through auxiliary objects.

`QEvent` itself is not a `QObject` derived, and as such, the same applies to all the derived events as well. That means no meta-information and no easy way to use from QML.

Since you are interested in a particular type of events, it would be easiest to create your own auxiliary object for those type of events, implement it in C++ and interface it to QML via signals you can attach handlers to.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a no go situation in terms of a straight forward solution. That at least confirms my fear that I have to keep rerouting event data through signals to QML slots. Thanks. I have to wonder though how on earth QML events are implemented. It seems that these are not based on `QEvent`s but something else...

Comment: @rbaleksandar - as the answer mentions, this is done through auxiliary objects. For example, `MouseArea` which is just for mouse and single touch events.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry about that. Thanks. I guess I might do that and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If `QGestureEvent` can be copy-constructed you could simply create a `Q_GADGET` based adapter:

```
class QmlGestureEvent : public QGestureEvent
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(...) // for the things you want to access from QML

public:
    QmlGestureEvent(const QGestureEvent &other) : QGestureEvent(other) {}
};
```

If it is not copy-constructable you'll have to add data members to the adapter and copy the values from the event.

Comment: No events support copy construction. This is a source of significant hackery needed to implement e.g. the state machine framework. Qt internally implements event cloning in a few places because of that. Hopefully it'll be cleaned up for Qt 6.

Comment: @KubaOber ah, I see. I just saw that `QEvent` itself had a copy constructor and `QGestureEvent` didn't seem to delete it, so I imagined the compiler would create a default one that calls the base class and then does member copy for the derived type's data

Comment: Let's put it this way: there is a copy constructor. But it is not supported. You have to audit Qt code to ensure that any events you intend to copy are in fact copyable. Another problem is that while a concrete event type might be copyable, what you really need is a virtual copy constructor (a `clone` that takes `QEvent`).

Comment: In this case the "copy" is more like a cast as the gadget class doesn't add any members. Might in fact actually work with a cast.